# Can we create stub JAR with just the Groovy Contract DSL file and without having the whole Producer code

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a producer service code base. I added contract DSL Groovy files to it and maven dependencies and plugins to the pom. I am running `mvn clean install` to generate the Stub jar, wiremock stub json and the tests.

Is it possible to create the Stub jar without having the whole code base? Can we create Stub jar just by having the Contract DSL?

Previously I tried the below command on the folder where the contracts are residing. This would create Wiremock Stub JSON from the Groovy Contracts

`mvn org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:convert`

I want to generate Stub Jar too by just using the Groovy contracts and not the building the whole code base. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is that happens out of the box. We create a sub hat with stubs and contracts. If you do mvn clean install you very the built code and the stub jar. You could create an assembly plugin setup to manually setup the jar.